# Как добавить таблицу в текст вопроса на StackOverflow?

Tags: обсуждение, форматирование

Доброго времени суток!
Я хочу задать вопрос на StackOverflow и, при этом, для наглядности, добавить таблицу с данными. С помощью каких тегов это можно реализовать?

Comment: В режиме кода (отступ 4 пробела) и символы `____` и `|` в помощь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

Новички как всегда не умеют в верстку таблиц через kbd, br, nbsp и code. Cкука.

<kbd>`id`</kbd>    <kbd>`Имя`</kbd>    <kbd>`Фамилия`</kbd><kbd>`Отчество`</kbd>   
<kbd>`1`</kbd>     <kbd>`Василий`</kbd><kbd>`Пупкин`</kbd> <kbd>`Фигвамович`</kbd>
<kbd>`2`</kbd>     <kbd>`Сами`</kbd>   <kbd>`Знаете`</kbd> <kbd>`Кто`</kbd>

P.S. А еще не на мете можно прикреплять таблицы обычным HTML через CTRL+M.

**UPD**: @Discord это еще цветочки по сравнению с этой милой варщающийся и тормознутой svg таблицей в которой внезапно можно выделять текст пока она крутится(нужно отдельно открыть её в новом окне). В хроме работает плохо, нужен Firefox.

[image: satan_table]

Comment: Жесть.​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Тут бы еще инструкцию, как это удобно делать. А то задать вопрос - уже отдельный подвиг.

Comment: @igumnov а Вы можете выложить исходный код своего сообщения?

Comment: @RussCoder Нажмите на кнопку править и посмотрите.

Comment: @igumnov на мете кнопка править не работает. Но если нажать на `изменен 2 июл в 19:51`, а потом на источник, то посмотреть можно.

Answer (score 5):

Для этой цели есть простой и удобный [инструмент](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html). Автором  является пользователь Senseful, который разработал это приложение именно для Stack Exchange. Пример:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               Col1                |    Col2    | NumCol |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| Value 1                           | Value 2    |    123 |
| This is a row with only one cell  |            |        |
| This row is testing html entities | Test       |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

Другие примеры [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139013/).

Comment: Если в таблице в основном текст, а не код, то следует добавлять перед ней `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, иначе она раскрашивается как код и выглядит странно.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел отличный инструмент для создания Markdown-таблиц: [Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

From [Allowed HTML Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909):

> We do not (and will not) allow `<table>` tags. Sorry. This is intentional and by design. If you need a quick and dirty "table", use `<pre>` and ASCII layout.

```
<pre>            - pre-element displayed in a fixed width font and and 
                   unchanged line breaks.
```

[Подробнее о форматировании](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)